# Eclipse not have build entire workspace checkbox when select clean

Tags: java, eclipse

[My eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2YC3.png)

Why my eclipse not have build entire workspace checkbox when select project > clean?
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

[Image from tutorialspoint.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ixL.png)

Answer (score 2):

That part of the dialog is only shown if you do not have 'Project > Build Automatically' selected.

This can also be configured in the Preferences in 'General > Workspace > Build'